# Strong and weak convergence in $L^p((-1,+\infty))$ exercise

Tags: convergence-divergence

I can't solve this exercise:

> Consider the sequence of function  $f_n:[1,+\infty\rangle
> > \to\mathbb{R},\;n\in\mathbb{N}$
>
> $$f_n(x):=\frac{x-1}{\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}\ln(x+\frac{1}{n})}$$
>
> Study the convergence properties of the sequence (pointwise almost
>   everywhere, srong in $L^p(1,+\infty)$ for $1\le p\le +\infty$, weak
>   for $1\le p< +\infty$, $\mathrm{weak}^{*}$ in $L^{\infty}$)

For the pointwise limit a.e. I obtain:

$$f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^{3/2}\ln(x)}\quad\forall x\in (1,+\infty)$$

But as soon as I try to check if there is some $1\le p < +\infty$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}||f-f_n||_{L^p}=0$$

i.e.:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_1^{+\infty}|f(x)-f_n(x)|^p dx=0$$

I don't know how to go on. Same problem with $p=+\infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please, add your attempts so the community members can help you!

Comment: I can only compute the pointwise almost everywhere limit, then as soon as I start computing the limit to test the strong convergence I can't go on

Comment: may I ask you to add that in your post? I'm not sure if i can help you, but somebody else knows for sure.